# Is there a way to read code from SAS7BVEW files?

Tags: sas

I want to open a .sas7bvew file and read the view definition. I know that it's possible to get the code by running `proc describe view` but I would prefer to read the definition from the file.

Is this possible, or will I need to go back and query the definitions from SAS? Bonus points if there's a way to view it outside of SAS EG but I'd still be interested if it's opening it through there somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of anyone deciphering the sas7bvew binary. sas7bdat and sas7bcat but not sas7bvew. Normally, the 1st 1-2k of binary is the header. You would want to look after that for content. Suggest using 010 Editor. The Python guys may have looked at it.

Comment: It always feels bad accepting a negative answer, but unless someone else comes along seems like this is about right. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: My code can probably grab the header. The next section is the descriptors. Are you a developer willing to tackle the binary (C#/python/etc.)? If you put a sample file out there, I am happy to take a look. Sick right now, be patient, but can pull it up and provide pointers.

Comment: The complexities and the history here are enormous. SAS has numerous binary formats such as the sas7bdat. In the past, when people deciphered them, a lot of bad things happened. Is the layout of data a copyright or not? Can you copy a file's physical construct. Ultimately, the EU ruled against MS in the early 2000s and against SAS a decade later. I am 100% not a lawyer but programmers, like me, have to be judicious when we touch these areas. Happy to help but at the risk of my livelihood? The negative is probably the correct answer. HTH.

Comment: thanks for the offer and explanation. My situation is not so urgent that we need to invest time into working on it, and certainly I don't need to risk any issues around copyright. I can read the view definitions other ways, it just would have been easier/nicer if there'd been a really easy way to do it directly from the definition files. I hope you get well soon!